# How to identify ServerEndPoint of different packages in Java Websocket Server?

Tags: java, javascript, websocket

I'm using WebSocket for bi-directional communication between Javascript client and Java Server and here is my project hierarchy.
[image]

I have created a javascript client **websocket.js**

```
        var webSocket;

        var messages = document.getElementById("messages");

        function openSocket()
        {   

            if(webSocket !== undefined && webSocket.readyState !== WebSocket.CLOSED)
            {
               writeResponse("WebSocket is already opened.");
                return;
            }

            webSocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8181/TeenPattiWebRCF/echo");


            webSocket.onopen = function(event)
            {

                if(event.data === undefined)
                 return;

                writeResponse(event.data);
            };

            webSocket.onmessage = function(event){
                writeResponse(event.data);
            };

            webSocket.onclose = function(event){
                alert("Connection closed "+event.data);
                writeResponse("Connection closed");
            };
        }

        function send(){
            var text = document.getElementById("messageinput").value;
            webSocket.send(text);
        }

        function closeSocket(){
           webSocket.close();
        }

        function writeResponse(text){
            messages.innerHTML +="<br/>"+text;
        }
```

and here is my Java Server

```
@ServerEndpoint("/echo") 
public class EchoServer
{   
@OnOpen
public void onOpen(Session session)
{
    System.out.println(session.getId() + " has opened a connection"); 
    try
    {
        session.getBasicRemote().sendText("Connection Established");
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}


@OnMessage
public void onMessage(String message, Session session)
{

  for(Session singleSession : session.getOpenSessions()){
  singleSession.getBasicRemote().sendText("Hello");
  }
 }
  @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session){
    System.out.println("Session " +session.getId()+" has ended");
  }  
}
```

I have index.jsp and I'm calling openSocket() function of websocket.js on onload.

I'm running my project on Tomcat with HTTP/1.1 port number 8181.
But connection is not establishing between server and client and displaying connection closed.
   1. Is anything wrong while instantiating 
       webSocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8181/TeenPattiWebRCF/echo"); ?
     Debugger showing Ready State=3.
   2. What if I have two different ServerEndPoint in two different packages with same channel name (say, @ServerEndpoint("/echo")) ?

Comment: Ad 2) if that is the case, your application is most likely not deployed. Check servel log for more details.